# Can anyone see where I'm going wrong with this srcset?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, srcset

I'm building a responsive Wordpress website. The blog feed has a list of stories which have a title and an image. The image sizes should be as follows:

1. up to 479px wide - 140x140px (stories are displayed in a list)
2. over 480px wide - 360x190px (stories are displayed in a row of 3)

I've been trying to use SRCSET for this so that the 140x140px image would be loaded for browsers up to 479px and the 360px image would be loaded for browsers 480px and over.

I've googled and read literally every bit of documentation out there on sizes and srcset but I just can't get my head around it. So far I've come up with the following:

```html
<img
  src="http://placekitten.com/140/140"
  srcset="
    http://placekitten.com/140/140 140w,
    http://placekitten.com/360/190 360w"
  sizes="
    (max-width: 479px) 140px,
    (min-width: 480px) 360px,
    100vw"
  alt=""
  class="lazyload"
/>
```

Unfortunately all this does is display the 360x190px at every width, despite the actual src of the image being set to the 140x140px image.

Can anyone see what I've missed? I think it's the sizes that I'm most confused about. I added in media queries like documented but they don't seem to be applied?

Thank you!

Comment: Please share your **generated markup**. PHP is a server-side language and cannot be rendered by the code snippet.

Comment: Hi! I've updated it to use placekitten images but I'm not sure it's worked? I only have it running locally so the code was just an example of what I'm working with.

Comment: Which browser are you using ? Your code in the question is working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this `srcset` strategy on the `<img>` element depends on the fact that **the browser has not cached the image yet**. This strategy is meant to save the bandwidth for the browser. So, if you start off with a wide viewport, the browser simply fetches the larger of the two images and will no longer fallback to the smaller one even if you resize.

If you want to force the browser to load images at various viewport breakpoints, use `<picture>` instead:

```html
 <picture alt="" class="lazyload">
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/360x190" media="(min-width: 480px)" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x140" />
 </picture>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately I've tried copying and pasting that code just to test and it still displays the 360px wide one when my browser is under 479px. That's how I logically thought it should work - up to 479px then use the 140px image, and 480px and over then use the 360px image, but it just seems to ignore it. I've tried incognito mode too just incase it's caching but no luck!

Comment: @AliGreen It works, but you have to test it in a lower resolution first and clear your cache. Think of this: when the browser has a higher resolution version of the picture, it will not want to downsize to a smaller image even after you shrink the viewport.

Comment: I'm testing on a retina Macbook pro - that's 2x resolution isn't it? I thought that may be the problem but I checked in Chrome at 130px width (using the responsive tools) and still coming out as 360px width - very odd!

https://imgur.com/a/RVLjx

Comment: @AliGreen You should probably use the `<picture>` element instead: see my updated answer. The `srcset` attribute on the `<img>` element only serves to tell the browser which image to load at runtime.

Comment: Thank you - that works in Chrome! Only issue is that it won't work in IE11, but it's the picturefill polyfill for that isn't it?

Comment: @AliGreen Unfortunately `<picture>` is not supported in IE, but there is a polyfill for that: https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/

Comment: Great stuff. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code below.

```html
<picture>
              <source class="img-fluid" srcset="//www.fillmurray.com/140/140" media="(max-width: 479px)"><img class="img-fluid" src="//www.fillmurray.com/360/190">
            </picture>
```